# Is it possible to deploy PysimpleGUI to Heroku?

Tags: python, heroku, pysimplegui

I have a PysimpleGUI app integrated with a python script. I would like to deploy that app to the web through Heroku so other colleagues can interact with it. Is it possible?

EDIT:
So I tried PYSimpleGUIWeb and it works except for one thing. I cannot interact with the browse buttons to search for my files locally. They are not responding.

[image]

Here is my PysimpleGUI app:

```
sg.theme('DarkTeal9')
ttk_style = ''

layout =   [
        [sg.T(ttk_style)],
        [sg.Text('Text1', font=("Calibri", 20))],
        [sg.Text('   ')],
        [sg.Text('Text2:'), sg.Input(), sg.FileBrowse()],
        [sg.Text('Text3'), sg.Input(), sg.FileBrowse()],
        [sg.Text('Text4'), sg.Input(), sg.FileBrowse()],
        [sg.Button('Procesar',bind_return_key=True,use_ttk_buttons=True)], #,use_ttk_buttons=True
        [sg.Text('Ventana de progreso:')],
        [sg.Output(size=(75,25),key='inputbox')],
        [sg.Text('   ')]]
                    

window = sg.Window('Programme', resizable=True).Layout(layout) #, ttk_theme=ttk_style



while True: 
    event, values = window.Read()
    if event in (None, 'Exit'):
        break
        
    if event == 'Procesar':
        path1=values[0]
        path2=values[1]
        path3=values[2]

        generar_propuestas(path1,path2,path3) #llamamos a la función

    elif event == 'Process':
        for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.xlsx')):
            with open(filename,'rb') as f:
                pdf = f.read()
            
    
window.close()
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python

Comment: Take a look at the [PySimpleGUIWeb](https://pypi.org/project/PySimpleGUIWeb/) project.

Comment: How can I search for the files locally with sg.FileBrowse() ?

Comment: @RishabhDeepSingh PySimpleGUI does not run in a web browser. - at oj PySimpleGUIWeb does not have a major release. A lot of stuff are broken. Read the pypi page as well as follow this issue: https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/issues/142 A lot of things are simply not working. They are aware and you should consult with the developers or read their docs what's exactly it is capable of.

Comment: thanks for the info! We'll have to wait for further updates.. Cheers

Comment: @Tin True, he won't be able to get the UI working but APIs can work also for UI Django will work too. Maybe have to transport the code to that.